# How can add a row to a DataTable with a dynamic number of cells

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, datatables, row

I have this code that I use to create a new row in a DataTable that I use for inline editing in a MVC intranet.

Each row has 4 cells, two for editing data and two with edit and delete links.

This table was used to edit the values of TestFields, a table in our DB, create new ones, etc.

We had two headers, Name and Description, hence the two cells.

Now I'm using this same code to do something totally different.

The Headers are now the existing TestFields names, therefore I can have one header or 100.

So I need to be able to add a new row that has x cells depending on the number of TestFields objects, which I get from the model.

So this is what I had

```
  Name   Description
  --------------------------------
  Name1  Description1    Edit or Save Delete
  Name2  Description3    Edit or Save Delete
  Name1  Description1    Edit or Save Delete
```

Here I know I only need two cells + edit/save/delet links, so no problem

The new table I need now looks like

```
  Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4   Name4 ...   
  --------------------------------
  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5   Edit or Save Delete
  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5   Edit or Save Delete
  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5   Edit or Save Delete
```

So that means that this bit of code

```
var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '',
                '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', '<a class="delete"
```

can be

```
var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['',
                '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', '<a class="delete"
```

or

```
var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '', '', '' ,'' ,'','','','',
                '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', '<a class="delete"
```

That depends on the number of TestFields I have.

This is the whole code for creating a new row.
Any ideas?

```
   $('#new').click(function (e) 
                e.preventDefault();

                **var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '',
            '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', '<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>']);**
                var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes(aiNew[0]);
                editRow(oTable, nRow, false);
                nEditing = nRow;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Here's the soluion

```
$('#new').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var fieldsCount = $("#FieldsCount").val();
            var row         = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < fieldsCount; i++) {
                row[i] = '';
            }

            row[fieldsCount]                = '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>';
            row[parseInt(fieldsCount) + 1]  = '<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>';

            var aiNew   = oTable.fnAddData(row);
            var nRow    = oTable.fnGetNodes(aiNew[0]);

            editRow(oTable, nRow, false);
            nEditing = nRow;
        });
```